# Java - Utilize avail data structure or create new data structure

Tags: java

My question is that when do we need to create new data structure and when should we use built-in data structure.

Assume, I have to read a file. Based on pattern matching, I have to get 3 properties. i.e `propertyA, propertyB, propertyC`

After gathering these 3 properties from 5 files, I have to write to a database.

**Option1:**

Create a reader which reads a file will return a `Map` or `Json`.
Class which calls reader will receive returned dataStructure. In this case, it is either `Map or Json`.

I will create another map in the caller class `Map<StringFileName, MapReturnedData>`.

If I get all the data from all the files, I will populate it into database.

**Option2**

Instead of `Map or Json` create user defined class with 3 properties and its getters and setters.

Which one we have to use? If both are same, when we have to use user defined and built in?

Comment: Do you plan on doing this task repeatedly in your software?  If so, then a third option would be to create a POJO class representing the data read from file, and then use something like Hibernate to persist it to the database.  If you don't plan on using an ORM tool, then either of your approaches should work with JDBC.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have to repeatedly to do these jobs in different thread. It is a spark job. Each thread does what I explained. And Database is hbase. Please advise me

Comment: I would follow @TimBiegeleisen advice. I do not see performance gains from a custom structure for 3 properties in 5 files. 15 read/store * N or just 3 * 5? You may get better performance from getting the pattern matching right

Answer (score 0):

In my view it comes down to how much processing will you do of the data.  If the 3 properties are just being read and then written to the DB, Option 1 is a straight forward choice.  It may perform better as it may reduce the number of objects being created.  On the other hand, if the data needs formatting and conversion, if you may be processing some fields to create a new field etc, it will be easier for others to understand if you read the data into a well written class structure and encapsulate some of that processing within the class (Option 2).

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have large file and your data structure was defined means you have data which is easily supported by built in data types, then you can use `Map` or `Json` way to get data from file and put it into DB.
   If you are using NOSql database then 1st option was good.
   If you have some processing after read data from file then this option was good.
2. As per your test scenario, you have to use your own `POJO` with 3 properties. i.e `propertyA, propertyB, propertyC` If just read and write then this option is ideal choice.

When you are using POJO option this will provide you better maintenance and flexibility to add or remove properties.
if you want to your own mark then go to user defined option.

> When to use user defined and built in.

Built in data types are general purpose data types like `int, float array, etc`.

User defined data types are those that user / programmer himself defines. For example, classes, interfaces. If your data is not suitable for built in data types then only use user defined data types.

Decide based on your data & how you want to manage that data.
Fore more detail please go through [this link](http://dtkachenko.blogspot.in/2011/11/data-structures-and-algorithms-when-to.html).